# Нужна ли запятая перед и

Tags: запятая

Правильно ли расставлены знаки препинания в предложении:
Есть в нашем районе деревенька, в которой из 29 домов жилых - три, и живут в каждом из них по одному жителю: две женщины и мужчина.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласен с вами, Вера. Лучше двоеточие, так далее идет пояснение. Тире тоже возможно, но придаст другой смысл: неожиданность.

Comment: Мне кажется, постановка тире будет обозначать  добавочный (присоединительный) характер последнего сочетания, а это  совсем не обязательный вариант. Пояснение здесь вполне уместно и на первом плане.

Comment: Тире обозначает неожиданное присоединение: вдруг оказывается эти два жителя - две женщины и мужчина. Но здесь не тот оттенок. Здесь именно пояснение. После двоеточия можно поставить " а именно".

Answer (score 2):

"По одному жителю" - это не обобщающие слова, а определяемые для приложений "две женщины и мужчина", носящих пояснительный характер, поэтому вместо двоеточия надо поставить тире

Comment: а нужна ли запятая перед и

Answer (score 0):

Перед И запятая нужна, так как предложение сложное. Остальные знаки допустимы: двоеточие заменяет второе тире.

Comment: А вот живЁт или живУт? И чем в предложении является "по одному жителю"?

Comment: А я считала, что это предложение с двумя однородными придаточными и перед и запятая не нужна. Спасибо

Comment: Предложение "...и живут в каждом из них..." не является придаточным по отношению к первой части

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Очень благодарна

Answer (score 0):

Интересное предложение, но чтобы правильно поставить знаки препинания, надо определить его структуру.

1) Это всё-таки ССП, хотя его можно было бы представить и в виде СПП, немного изменив структуру: "Есть в нашем районе деревенька,  В КОТОРОЙ из 29 домов жилых – три И ГДЕ  живут в каждом доме  по одному жителю: две женщины и мужчина". Тогда запятая не ставилась бы.

2)  Второе предложение в составе ССП: «живут в каждом из них по одному жителю: две женщины и мужчина».  Его будем считать неопределенно-личным: сказуемое «живут по одному жителю» - глагол и тесно связанный  с ним  по смыслу счетный оборот.

И вот этот оборот если не обобщает, то распространяет/поясняет  сочетание "две женщины и мужчина".  Поэтому лучше пред ним поставить двоеточие, но можно и тире.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ